# Release a object immediately in arc mode

Tags: objective-c

Now,I want to release a object immediately in arc mode.I have thought long time.I looking forward to a help?

Answer (score 2):

If you declare any object with local scope then it will automatically release within this scope in arc.

For example,

```
 -(void)demoMethod{

    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]init];
    str = @"hello";
}
```

in above method `str` will release when control reach to `}` i.e end of the method.

Second thing you can release object by assigning `nil` to it.

Comment: In this case `i` is not an object, it's a variable with a primitive type. It won't ever be alloc'ed, retained or retained.

Comment: @Cyrille : Yeah, it was just  example  to understand. Edited it with `string`. Now it is object... :)

Comment: But it is a constant string, so it won't be released either :)